# Why is an ultrasonic transducer able to send energy into a tank without an opposing surface?

Tags: classical-mechanics, acoustics, vibrations, ultrasound

The diagram shows an ultrasonic transducer stuck to the bottom of an ultrasonic cleaning tank full of water/detergent. It's not supported at the opposing end - just hanging off the bottom of the tank. The piezoelectrics vibrate, causing the compression bolt to extend/contract at around 20-40Khz typically. This vibration is transmitted through the tank to the liquid where it causes cavitation, and cleans stuff.

Since it is unsupported at the opposing end, why is this energy transmitted to the tank?

[image]

Comment: When your phone is set to vibrate, how can you feel it going off in your hand since one side is unsupported?

Comment: @JonCuster Good point - and yes similarly I don't understand that either! If I were to carry out the vibration in the diagram above at say 1 Hz (and it be a slow gradual sine wave movement, not square) , I don't think there would be any detectable force on the tank. So is it through inertia that the energy is being transmitted?

Comment: The center of mass of the piezo driver (M1, M2, piezo) changes, but one side is firmly attached to the tank. The piezo does work to shake it back and forth.

Comment: @JonCuster But this work is done to the central compession bolt, extending and contracting it?

Comment: Which then tries to pull M1 and M2 together, but M1 is attached to an object and M2 is free to move. So M1 exerts a force pulling on the tank. Then the piezo relaxes, and M1 pushes on the tank to force M2 away from it. Without any surface tractions (and providing M1=M2) the piezo unit would vibrate in place. But that isn't the case once you attach M1 to the tank.

Comment: @JonCuster "M1 is attached to an object and M2 is free to move. So M1 exerts a force pulling on the tank" - But this is what I don't understand - surely M2 should just move freely in this case, accomodating the changing piezo, and leaving M1 (which is pretty well constrained by sheet metal to a stationary object (the US bath)) stationary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inertial mass of the transducer assembly itself furnishes the "backing" force that lets the transducer propel energy into the tank. As the transducer deflects, the deflection wave bounces off the mass of the assembly and heads away in the opposite direction- that is, *into the tank* instead of out the bottom of the transducer assembly.

This is called an *inertially-clamped condition* and is BTW the manner in which lasers are used to crush the fusion capsules inside a fusion reactor. The energy is dumped into the capsule so fast that the inertia of the capsule itself prevents the capsule from "getting out of the way".

The inertially-clamped condition (also known as the *mass-controlled regime*) can be mathematically modeled and used in design. For example, if an anvil is a certain amount heavier than the hammer head striking it, then very little of the hammer's velocity gets transferred to the anvil, which just sits still while the hammer head  bounces off it and flies away.

Comment: That makes sense, though finding it hard to find any further information on this on the net. DO you know anywhere I could read more about this? Many thanks

Comment: The general topic is referred to as *acoustical impedance matching and mismatching*.